# do i need to rewrite my twisted chat server if i want to support web sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, twisted

I have an existing chat socket server built on top of twisted's NetstringReceiver class. There exist Android/iOS clients that work with it fine. Apparently web sockets use a different protocol and so it is unable to connect to my server.

Does a different chat server need to be written to support web sockets?

Answer (score 0):

“Yes.”

If you'd like a more thorough answer, you'll have to include more information in your question.

Comment: can you tell me what more informations is needed? i am using twisted, have ios/android clients connecting to the socket server using their respective socket client libraries, and i'd like for there to be a single solution for ios/android/web

Comment: I would recommend using SockJS with something like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/txsockjs for web, and layering your existing protocol on top of that.  The necessary information to be more detailed would be an explanation of what you've already tried and how it didn't work, or perhaps a simplified minimal example of your protocol.